# Python pipe with single input and multiple outputs

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, publish-subscribe

I'm familiar with `multiprocessing.Pipe`, but am looking for something which can make a copy of the input data and send it on to multiple output consumers. I understand that Queues support multiple consumers, but in that case each input message will only go to one consumer, instead of all of them.

I'd like each input object to get output to **every** consumer:

```
              ↱ Output A
Input -> Pipe → Output B
              ↳ Output C
```

I'd like the number of output consumers to be able to change at runtime. I don't need bidirectional data flow. Seems like this could be called a pub/sub pattern, but I can't find any implementations of that for local use.

I think I could implement this with three (or n) individual Pipes and just iterate over them to write the input into each pipe, but that doesn't seem like a scalable/clean approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are your consumers? Are they running in different threads or processes?

Comment: @satoru Each consumer is a different process.

Comment: You should post your multiple streams approach as an answer, then at least if people see the question and think that is as good an approach as any you will get upvotes indicating that.

Comment: Itertools.tee comes to mind, it is very close in purpose to pipes. Would need particular constraints on consumers to use it directly though.

Comment: What kind of data?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tadhg, here's my naive approach, along with some brief test code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe

class PubSub(object):
    _consumers = set()

    def send(self, obj):
        for consumer in self._consumers:
            consumer[1].send(obj)

    def subscribe(self):
        new_pipe = Pipe(duplex=False)
        self._consumers.add(new_pipe)
        return new_pipe[0]

    def unsubscribe(self, pipe):
        for consumer in self._consumers:
            if consumer[0] == pipe:
                self._consumers.remove(consumer)
                return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pubsub
    a = pubsub.PubSub()
    z = a.subscribe()
    y = a.subscribe()
    x = a.subscribe()

    a.send("fred")
    print(z.recv()) # fred
    print(y.recv()) # fred
    print(x.recv()) # fred

    a.unsubscribe(x)
    a.send("derf")
    print(z.recv()) # derf
    print(y.recv()) # derf
    print(x.recv()) # Traceback: EOFError
```

I'm sure there are race conditions waiting to bite me ;-)